# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} (3x-\sqrt{9x^2 - 7x})$

Tags: limits

I'm having a hard time simplifying this.

As usual I multiplied by the conjugate:

$$  (3x-\sqrt{9x^2 - 7x}) \cdot \left( \frac{3x+\sqrt{9x^2 - 7x}}{3x+\sqrt{9x^2 - 7x}}\right)$$

$$\frac{7x}{3x+\sqrt{9x^2-7x}}$$

Now I tried to divide all terms by  $x$ by it still gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \infty}}$. What am I missing?

Comment: It's 7 and not 7x at the numerator Trey ...

Comment: @Isham  your recent edit was entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @amWhy It's more aesthetics written this way but I agree with you not that necessary

Comment: What do you get when you divide numerator and denominator by $x$?  I think this must be where your mistake was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done everything right so far.  So we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{7x}{3x+\sqrt{9x^2-7x}}$$

Now we factor out $x$ from $\sqrt{9x^2 - 7x} = \sqrt{x^2(9 - \frac 7x)}$ to get $|x|\sqrt{9 - \frac 7x}$.  Now, given that $x$ is becoming arbitrarily large (positive), we take $|x| = x$.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{7x}{3x+x\sqrt{9-\frac 7x}}$$

Factoring out the $x$ from numerator and denominator and canceling gives us:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{7}{3+\sqrt{9-\frac 7x}} = \frac 76$$

Comment: I didn't see this... Sorry for taking so long to accept it

Answer (score 2):

$$  (3x-\sqrt{9x^2 - 7}) *  \frac{(3x+\sqrt{9x^2 - 7})}{(3x+\sqrt{9x^2 - 7})}=\frac{7}{3x+\sqrt{9x^2-7}}\ne\frac{7x}{3x+\sqrt{9x^2-7}}$$

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I just edited my question

Comment: Looks like this was downvoted.

Comment: +1 Well some people have not seen that op's question has changed

Comment: That was 23 minutes ago that the asker notified you of the edit, and the OP did, after all, have $7x$ correctly written in the numerator all along.  Never good to rush on an answer and always good to check things out first with the asker when you see discrepancies.  Notified you of the edit within two minutes of your post, in fact.